Compute the integral of exp function over a multi-dimension space
Let $a, z\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $Z:=\{z: -1\leq a^{\top}z\leq 0, \|z\|_{\infty}\leq 10\}$.
Can we compute
$$
\int_{Z}\exp(a^{\top}z) dz
$$
by using some known algorithms? Or this problem is NP-hard?
Such a problem arises in one of my recent studies, which focuses on the integral of a moment generating function. I then begin with a tony problem.
a reference that may be helpful:
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Computing+the+Volume%2C+Counting+Integral+Points%2C+and+Exponential+Sums&btnG=

Why is this integral important to you?
